# How can I take a google form's user input value and respond with a result from a lookup table, automatically?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Let's say I have a list of 10,000+ serial numbers in a google sheet, and I have a google form where a user inputs their serial number (1 per form submission).  If there is a match between their serial number and the one in my table (stored in a google sheet for example), how can I have the form respond with a yes/no (after they submit their form's inputs) that they have a match?  Ideally the yes/no response would automatically be emailed to them, but just showing results on a screen is okay too.  The list of serial numbers in my google sheets database would be over 10,000 serial numbers easily.  Is it even possible for a google sheet to automatically run a script when a new set of data is submitted by the form?

I am aware that google form responses can be save in a google sheet, but I need something automatied that will respond to user input in real time, rather than open a spreadsheet of user inputs and respond if the user has a match or not hours, perhaps days after their initial input.

I thought of maybe approaching it just using a google sheet, but unfortunately I don't know how to limit the input to one user at a time (otherwise I can see people over-writing each other serial numbers before someone clicks a control button on the spreadsheet to get a result).

Comment: You cannot.  There is no programmatic interaction possible with a google form until the form is submitted.

Comment: That's okay. I want some sort of results message (or email sent) soon after the form's inputs are submitted.

Comment: Use Event Objects and an `OnFormSubmit` trigger; use `indexOf` to find a match between the Form serial# and the Sheets table; _if_ you find a match, then get the contact inform from the table, and send the email. Pretty sure that are a several examples of this on StackOverflow.